# Data is not being received using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using a retrofit to get Json data but something is wrong. No data is being received.

The following is my model class

```
public class DataList {
@SerializedName("pariyojanaId")
    @Expose
    private Float pariyojanaId;
    @SerializedName("projectStatus")
    @Expose
    private String projectStatus;
    @SerializedName("heading")
    @Expose
    private String heading;
    @SerializedName("projectNumber")
    @Expose
    private Float projectNumber;
    @SerializedName("fieldTitle")
    @Expose
    private String fieldTitle;
    @SerializedName("targetedGroup")
    @Expose
    private String targetedGroup;

//Getter Setter
}
```

My interface

```
public interface PariyojanaInterface {
@GET("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile")
Call<List<DataList>> getData(
        @Query("memberId") int id);
}
```

I have an API interface which is working.
Below is my retrofit function.

```
 apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
    Call<List<DataList>> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
    Log.e("url", call.request().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DataList>> call, Response<List<DataList>> response) {
            Log.e("url", "hello");
            posts =  response.body();
            adapter = new PariyojanaAdapter(posts,getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DataList>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

When i run this program, upto the line

```
Log.e("url", call.request().toString());
```

I am getting response but after that in line

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataList>>() {}
```

I think there is some problem. I am not able to run my program past this.  Can anybody please help me.

Comment: Post your JSON response from Api

Comment: its somewhat like this 
{"data":[{"pariyojanaId":81,"projectStatus":"On_Progress","heading":"Project.","projectNumber":29,"fieldTitle":"कृषि ","targetedGroup":"बाल बालिका"},{"pariyojanaId":80,"projectStatus":"On_Progress","heading":"Final test for samiti tole","projectNumber":28,"fieldTitle":"कृषि ","targetedGroup":"आदिबासी"}

Comment: I think your model class is object but you modeled as a list . you can change like this  === call.enqueue(new Callback<DataList>(){} @Sudeep

Comment: post the json you want to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant directly access the array without going through the outer object,you will need one more pojo class like this :

**DataResponse.java**

```
    public class DataResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<DataList> data = null;

public List<DataList> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<DataList> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

Change all `List<DataList>` to `DataResponse` i.e, convert your network call like this :

```
apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
Call<DataResponse> call = apiInterface.getData(id);
Log.e("url", call.request().toString());
call.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
        Log.e("url", "hello");
        ArrayList<DataList> post_list =  new ArrayList<>(response.body().getData());
        adapter = new PariyojanaAdapter(post_list,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

and change interface like this

```
    public interface PariyojanaInterface {
@GET("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile")
Call<DataResponse> getData(
        @Query("memberId") int id);
}
```

As i have mentioned, your endpoint is returning an object, not an array. So specify an object as return params for your network callbacks

Comment: thank you for you response.  but i dont know why data are stil not coming. 
 The line         Log.e("url", "hello");
is not being printed. :(  The code is not going inside call.enqueue

Comment: what is the value of `Log.e("error",t.getMessage());`

Comment: There is no error just data is not coming.  Some logs are 
"Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView"


and ----&&---  "Unable to resolve host "uat.nirc.com.np": No address associated with hostname"

Comment: have you declared internet permission in android manifest file, if so share the api url you are using

Comment: yes i have declared the internet permission. The api i am using is 
https://uat.nirc.com.np:8443/GWP/projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile?memberId=2

Comment: i think you have mistyped your base url. set your base url like this  `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://uat.nirc.com.np:8443/GWP/").....`

Comment: same error as before or new one? can you  post complete error?

Comment: New error. It is not taking that base url. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: uat.nirc.com.np:8443/GWP/

Comment: When i give base url to Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() .baseUrl("https://uat.nirc.com.np:8443/GWP/"), it is same result as before

Comment: i used this `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://uat.nirc.com.np:8443/GWP/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();` and got the correct response

Comment: i dont know what is wrong. Can you please push the code in git?

Answer (score 1):

Try this flow

```
               try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultJSONResponse);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                strid = o.getString("pariyojanaId");
                                strstatus = o.getString("projectStatus");

                                showMethod();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```